# Xampp sub domain not accessible via Edge and Firefox?

Tags: apache, xampp, httpd.conf

I have setup a sub-domain using `httpd-vhosts.conf` file on Xampp (Windows), the sub domain is accessible via `Chrome` and `Opera` on `subdomain.localhost` but `Firefox` and `Edge` can't resolve the address. However, `localhost` (the main domain) works on all browsers.

```
#localhost

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias www.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

#subdomain

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/subdomain"
    ServerName subdomain.localhost
    ServerAlias www.subdomain.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Here's my solution:
After you create virtual hosts in httpd-vhosts.conf you must **add your sub-domain to hosts file**. It is located at `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` in windows.
You should add

`127.0.0.1    subdomain.localhost`